# Browser falsely flags as malware

Tags: google-chrome, malware, microsoft-edge, github

I'm trying to distribute my application through Github. I packaged it into a exe and released it on Github under releases.

But when I or anyone tries to download it, the browser flags it as malware and doesn't let them download it. How do I fix this. (My app is open-source and obviously not malware)
[image]

I think it needs to be digitally signed but I have no idea how to do it. I assume its a fairly common issue and has a simple solution.

Comment: Are you sure browsers are actually preventing the download? Or are they perhaps just nagging? Files generally need to build a reputation.

Comment: @Daniel_B They are strongly discouraging

Comment: That's still different from blocking. With your example it's likely just nagging because it's an exe file rather than say a zip.